# organising a .csv file in R

Tags: r, spatial, analysis

I'm programming a script for the calculation of cover around points in R. 
I have two inputs: an IMG raster file, and a .csv with all the points.

I've used this script:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

#load in raster and locality data
map <- raster('map.IMG')
sites <- read.csv('points.csv', header=TRUE)

#convert lat/lon to appropirate projection
coordinates(sites)  <-  c("X",  "Y")
proj4string(sites)  <- CRS("+init=epsg:27700")

#extract values to points
Landcover<-extract (map, sites, buffer=2000)
extraction <- lapply(Landcover, function(serial) prop.table(table(serial)))

# Write .csv file
lapply(extraction, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'test2.csv'  , append= T, sep=',' ))
```

I get a .csv file in my map, but the data isn't organised in the way I would like it to be.

There a three columns in the csv file. One with 'x', one with 'Freq' (Which I think is the code for every class in my image) and one with the cover part, somewhere between 0-1. See the image included.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iirav.png)

I want to have on the rows the serial and classes, and under that the correct serial with it's coverage.

Also every point isn't named, so I can't see which is which. In the points.csv I have for example a 'serial' code for every point, which i would like to use for that.

Can somebody steer me in the right direction?

I hope I have been clear with my questions, thank in advance!

Comment: Unless you provide any sample data and expected output , it's tough to find a solution.

Comment: Please provide a working example (code, including data generated by code)